# Обращение к коду в php сценарии

Tags: php

Есть доступная сумма $rub и ссылка "Забрать сумму", есть обработчик который контролирует какая сумма доступна, вопрос такой : как встроить обработчик в саму страницу с суммой, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку обработчик выполнялся и каким методом передавать $rub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю что-то вроде этого

```
<a href="#" onclick="get_money('<?=floatval($rub)?>'); return false">Забрать</a>
<script>
function get_money(rub)
{
    $.post('/get_money.php', 'rub='+rub, function(result){
         alert(result);
    })
}
</script>
```

Ну и соответственно в файле get_money.php обрабатывайте $_POST['rub']

Comment: А без JS можно реализовать?